# Beginner type conversion

Tags: c, graphics, type-conversion, mingw, codeblocks

I am extremely new to programming in general, so please forgive my noobishness. I am trying to scale down the res[?] array in the function below. I know the problem that the res[?]*(multiplier/100) is creating a decimal answer instead of the required format which is an integer therefore I need to convert the result before it is plugged into the res[?].

I did think of turning res[] array into a double but I wasnt sure whether the initwindow(?,?) was compatible with integer values.

I am on mingw with code blocks. the linker and compiler has customized setting made by my professor. I am on Plain\basic C???

I tried to apply the techniques this website used about the truncating conversion. But doesn't seem to work. http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/round.html
Debugger watcher shows that res[?] is equivalent to 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics_lib.h>
#include <math.h>


int res[2]//contains a array which contains the vertical and horizontal detected resolution from main()
void function(res)
    {
    printf("Please note the lowest resolution available is 800x600\n");
    printf("Please enter percentage ratio % below 100:");
    scanf("%d",&multiplier);
    res[1]=(int)(res[1]*(multiplier/100));
    res[2]=(int)(res[2]*(multiplier/100));

    blah blah blah blah.............

    initwindow(res[1],res[2]) //from custom header that my professor made which initializes basic graphics window 
    return;
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: Try something simpler first to verify your basic assumptions and conceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `multiplier` is an `int` to match the `%d` format.

`multiplier/100` is guaranteed to be zero (if the user follows directions and provides a number less than 100).  You can do `(res[x]*multiplier)/100` to make sure the multiply happens first (you're probably okay without the parentheses, but rather than think about order of operations why not be explicit?)

The cast to `int` is unnecessary, because an `int` divided by another `int` is always an `int`.

Unless your professor has done some very interesting things, you should also note that a two-element array such as res would have elements `res[0]` and `res[1]`, not `res[1]` and `res[2]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Got me unstuck from a 1 hour mad search through the code and internet.
Also I never thought the multiplier would go to zero. 
And also even though I accidentally used the wrong array number, the array somehow did work.
I'm guessing my initial code would have worked had I changed the multiplier to a float type.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `multiplier` variable is an `int`, so the result of `multiplier/100` expression will be 0 in all cases.

Also, it's a good programming practice to check the validity of user's input.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare `multiplier` before you use it:

```
int multiplier;
printf("Please note the lowest resolution available is 800x600\n");
printf("Please enter percentage ratio % below 100:");
scanf("%d",&multiplier);
```

And the index is staring from 0 not 1. And you should initialize `res[0]` and `res[1]` before using them. So:

```
res[0] = 800;
res[1] = 600;
```

And the division of multiplier by 100 will truncate to 0, try this without casting as it will be automaticly converted:

```
res[1]=(multiplier*res[0])/100;
res[1]=(multiplier*res[1])/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to cast in this situation because the conversion is done implicitly . you only need a cast to assign the content of a variable to a variable of different type .